# npm run build doesn't generate dist files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, mdbootstrap

sorry for my bad english.

Last time, npm run build is working fine. But after I wrote few lines and try to run this command "npm run build" I got an error of `Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.`

So I tried to reset to the last commit, so that I can build successfully, unfortunately, I'm facing again this error.

Normally when I try to run this command npm run build, I got some generated files in /dist but now, it says build complete but it doesn't generate files.

I tried to run this `npm run build --verbose` and received this error logs:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'build',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.9.0
npm info using node@v10.16.3
npm verb run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
npm info lifecycle mdbvue@5.8.0~prebuild: mdbvue@5.8.0
npm info lifecycle mdbvue@5.8.0~build: mdbvue@5.8.0

> mdbvue@5.8.0 build C:\xampp\htdocs\github\test1
> node build/build.js

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'prefix',
npm verb cli   '-g' ]
npm info using npm@6.9.0
npm info using node@v10.16.3
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 118ms
npm info ok
Hash: e52fb455f4b88a7ca5d5
Version: webpack 4.39.3
Time: 20198ms
Built at: 03/16/2020 1:44:51 PM
                                            Asset       Size       Chunks                    Chunk Names
                                        index.html  635 bytes               [emitted]
            static/css/app.fe4d61491ae85d4536da.css    266 KiB          app  [emitted]  [big]  app
        static/css/app.fe4d61491ae85d4536da.css.map    345 KiB          app  [emitted]         app
    static/css/vendors~app.3a3afdf0853d1018db0b.css    210 KiB  vendors~app  [emitted]         vendors~app
static/css/vendors~app.3a3afdf0853d1018db0b.css.map    288 KiB  vendors~app  [emitted]         vendors~app
                                static/favicon.ico   1.12 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Bold.39b2c30.woff2   48.8 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Bold.dc81817.woff   61.4 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Bold.e31fcf1.ttf    125 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ecdd509.eot   20.5 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Light.3b813c2.woff   60.9 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Light.46e48ce.ttf    124 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Light.69f8a06.woff2   48.2 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Light.a990f61.eot   20.4 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Medium.4d9f3f9.eot   20.9 KiB               [emitted]
        static/fonts/Roboto-Medium.574fd0b.woff2     49 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Medium.894a2ed.ttf    125 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Medium.fc78759.woff   61.5 KiB               [emitted]
        static/fonts/Roboto-Regular.2751ee4.woff2   48.1 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Regular.30799ef.eot   20.8 KiB               [emitted]
        static/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ba3dcd8.woff   60.3 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Regular.df7b648.ttf    123 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Thin.7500519.woff   60.2 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Thin.9499847.ttf    125 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Thin.954bbde.woff2   47.4 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/Roboto-Thin.dfe56a8.eot   21.2 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-brands-400.14c590d.eot    127 KiB               [emitted]
        static/fonts/fa-brands-400.3e1b2a6.woff2   72.8 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-brands-400.5e8aa9e.ttf    126 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-brands-400.df02c78.woff   85.5 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-regular-400.285a9d2.ttf   33.3 KiB               [emitted]
        static/fonts/fa-regular-400.5623624.woff   16.4 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-regular-400.aa66d0e.eot   33.6 KiB               [emitted]
        static/fonts/fa-regular-400.ac21cac.woff2   13.3 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-solid-900.3ded831.woff   95.7 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-solid-900.42e1fbd.eot    188 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-solid-900.896e20e.ttf    187 KiB               [emitted]
            static/fonts/fa-solid-900.d6d8d5d.woff2   73.6 KiB               [emitted]
                static/img/background.a052cf6.svg   62.9 KiB               [emitted]
                static/img/background.b568f39.jpg    130 KiB               [emitted]
            static/img/client-luljettas.622654c.svg   67.7 KiB               [emitted]
            static/img/client-marikina.db2eb35.svg   61.3 KiB               [emitted]
            static/img/fa-brands-400.bfa9c38.svg    675 KiB               [emitted]  [big]
            static/img/fa-regular-400.95f13e0.svg    141 KiB               [emitted]
                static/img/fa-solid-900.6ed5e3b.svg    820 KiB               [emitted]  [big]
                static/img/freelancer.b73e0f3.svg   60.6 KiB               [emitted]
        static/img/github-contributor.1ca5d17.svg   19.4 KiB               [emitted]
            static/img/ongoing-project.d524cda.svg   33.7 KiB               [emitted]
        static/img/software-engineer.a67e353.svg   20.4 KiB               [emitted]
                static/js/0.74eb05759f83e93c3bee.js   96.4 KiB            0  [emitted]
            static/js/0.74eb05759f83e93c3bee.js.map    109 KiB            0  [emitted]
                static/js/1.9276c013ba33d0268746.js   12.2 KiB            1  [emitted]
            static/js/1.9276c013ba33d0268746.js.map   6.07 KiB            1  [emitted]
            static/js/10.30636d71bc9ec5a0cc21.js   15.7 KiB           10  [emitted]
        static/js/10.30636d71bc9ec5a0cc21.js.map   12.7 KiB           10  [emitted]
            static/js/11.2fbcf17ae46cc72ee115.js   19.4 KiB           11  [emitted]
        static/js/11.2fbcf17ae46cc72ee115.js.map   19.3 KiB           11  [emitted]
            static/js/12.3239bb79db524273734d.js   16.1 KiB           12  [emitted]
        static/js/12.3239bb79db524273734d.js.map   13.5 KiB           12  [emitted]
            static/js/13.013706bf533f897712b6.js   11.6 KiB           13  [emitted]
        static/js/13.013706bf533f897712b6.js.map   5.48 KiB           13  [emitted]
                static/js/2.4e2db91152b7e097ceae.js   11.6 KiB            2  [emitted]
            static/js/2.4e2db91152b7e097ceae.js.map   5.49 KiB            2  [emitted]
                static/js/3.2f94cb6c4b1498655217.js   15.7 KiB            3  [emitted]
            static/js/3.2f94cb6c4b1498655217.js.map   12.8 KiB            3  [emitted]
                static/js/4.f81d6231701f95290493.js   17.2 KiB            4  [emitted]
            static/js/4.f81d6231701f95290493.js.map   16.1 KiB            4  [emitted]
                static/js/5.0423f1e8418588c74353.js   11.6 KiB            5  [emitted]
            static/js/5.0423f1e8418588c74353.js.map   5.48 KiB            5  [emitted]
                static/js/6.51dd3c223742f1f328bd.js   17.3 KiB            6  [emitted]
            static/js/6.51dd3c223742f1f328bd.js.map   16.6 KiB            6  [emitted]
                static/js/7.85b273216ca678d34cfd.js   19.4 KiB            7  [emitted]
            static/js/7.85b273216ca678d34cfd.js.map   20.8 KiB            7  [emitted]
                static/js/8.dd74116e839b7742a611.js   11.7 KiB            8  [emitted]
            static/js/8.dd74116e839b7742a611.js.map   5.51 KiB            8  [emitted]
                static/js/9.cf39afeccdd88108ac33.js   16.3 KiB            9  [emitted]
            static/js/9.cf39afeccdd88108ac33.js.map   13.9 KiB            9  [emitted]
            static/js/app.d79fa5cd7c434215023f.js   1020 KiB          app  [emitted]  [big]  app
        static/js/app.d79fa5cd7c434215023f.js.map    591 KiB          app  [emitted]         app
    static/js/vendors~app.e8ed788f97ce79ec1dbb.js    1.6 MiB  vendors~app  [emitted]  [big]  vendors~app
static/js/vendors~app.e8ed788f97ce79ec1dbb.js.map   1.96 MiB  vendors~app  [emitted]         vendors~app
Entrypoint app [big] = static/js/vendors~app.e8ed788f97ce79ec1dbb.js static/css/vendors~app.3a3afdf0853d1018db0b.css static/js/vendors~app.e8ed788f97ce79ec1dbb.js.map static/css/vendors~app.3a3afdf0853d1018db0b.css.map static/js/app.d79fa5cd7c434215023f.js static/css/app.fe4d61491ae85d4536da.css static/js/app.d79fa5cd7c434215023f.js.map static/css/app.fe4d61491ae85d4536da.css.map

Build complete.

Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

npm verb lifecycle mdbvue@5.8.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle mdbvue@5.8.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\github\test1\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\User1\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\User1\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\php\php71;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
npm verb lifecycle mdbvue@5.8.0~build: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\github\test1
npm info lifecycle mdbvue@5.8.0~postbuild: mdbvue@5.8.0
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 25731ms
npm info ok
```

I try to search for possible solution for this one. I tried to change from '/' to './' the assetsPublicPath in config/index.js. But unfortunately, it is not working.

Here's my config/index.js file

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.1.3
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    build: {
        env: require('./prod.env'),
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
        assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
        assetsPublicPath: './',
        productionSourceMap: true,
        // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
        // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
        // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
        // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
        productionGzip: false,
        productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
        // Run the build command with an extra argument to
        // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
        // `npm run build --report`
        // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
        bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
    },
    dev: {
        env: require('./dev.env'),
        port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
        autoOpenBrowser: true,
        assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
        assetsPublicPath: '/',
        proxyTable: {},
        // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
        // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
        // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
        // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
        // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
        cssSourceMap: false
    }
}
```

Here's my webpack.prod.conf.js

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = config.build.env

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    module: {
        rules: utils.styleLoaders({
        sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
        extract: true
        })
    },
    devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
        chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin()
        ],
        splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': env
        }),
        // extract css into its own file
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[md5:contenthash:hex:20].css')
        }),
        // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
        // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
        // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
        // you can customize output by editing /index.html
        // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: config.build.index,
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: true,
        minify: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: true
            // more options:
            // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
        },
        // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        }),
        // copy custom static assets
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
            to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
            ignore: ['.*']
        }
        ])
    ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
    const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
        asset: '[path].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: new RegExp(
            '\\.(' +
            config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
            ')$'
        ),
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
        })
    )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. It's just a _"tip"_, ie a useful piece of information

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But it seems like npm run build doesn't generate files. Normally when I try to run that command. I got some generated files. So when I try to push it in production, it doesn't building in production.

Comment: Looks like it's generating them in your `static` directory

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not really sure. But look on my project folder. 

I have a folder in the root folder of static folder but it only has two files, .gitkeep and favicon.ico

The other static folder is in /dist.

Here's the image: https://snipboard.io/Ah7tdW.jpg

Comment: build has been executed successfully and it has created dist folder. Seems like outside of the project folder 
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),

can you change them to 
ndex: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
because __dirname is current directory pointing to root of project.

Comment: and "Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work" isn't an error but it just a message that you need to a server to run index.html file rather then just clicking on index.html

Comment: Hi @souravsatyam I tried to change but it is not generating files. It doesn't work. Here's the snipboard. https://snipboard.io/aInpB0.jpg

Comment: @Star can you do a console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')) to check the directory because as your terminal log says it has created the bundle file.

Comment: It says C:\xampp\htdocs\github\test1\dist\index.html

Comment: When I tried to deploy, and try to open the website. It has a lot of errors, here are the errors. Please check the image: https://snipboard.io/Xfcryo.jpg

Comment: Up up up up up pleaseeee!!!!